# Parse table with HTML Agility Pack - Duplicate results

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

**I have this html table:**

```
<div style="width: 398px;">
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border: 2px solid #ffffff;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="parrafo-ver-negro">
                        <th class="borde-abajo borde-derecha" style="text-align: left;">Parada N&ordm;</th>
                        <th class="borde-abajo" style="text-align: left;">Destino</th>
                                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                        <td class="borde-derecha"><a class="parrafo-ver-negro link-nro-sms">5729</a></td>
                        <td class="parrafo_ver-gris letra9">103 NEGRO > Villa Gdor. Galvez<br>103 ROJO > Villa Gdor. GÃ¡lvez<br></td>
                                                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                        <td class="borde-derecha"><a class="parrafo-ver-negro link-nro-sms">5292</a></td>
                        <td class="parrafo_ver-gris letra9">103 NEGRO > Granadero Baigorria<br>103 ROJO > Mini Terminal Barrio Rucci<br></td>
                                                </tr>
                  </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**My code is this:**

```
public static List<Parada> parsear(string html)
    {
        int cual;
        int _parada;
        string _destino;
        List<Parada> lp = new List<Parada>();
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        foreach (HtmlNode tabla in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode fila in tabla.SelectNodes("//tr"))
            {
                cual = 1; _parada = 0; _destino = "";

                foreach (HtmlNode celda in fila.SelectNodes("//td"))
                {

                    if (cual == 1)
                    {
                        _parada = Int32.Parse(celda.InnerText);
                        cual = 2;
                    }
                    else if (cual == 2)
                    {
                        _destino = celda.InnerText;
                        cual = 1;

                        lp.Add(new Parada(_parada, _destino));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return lp;
    }
```

I should end up with two elements of List of Parada (the first TR I have to ignore, since it's the header), but instead I have 6, instead of two.
What's wrong with the code? 
I've tried many things but with the same result.

Thanks.

Comment: Debugging, modifying table, td, and tr with and without //, changing the location of the call of lp.Add(), but it seems one of the foreach is wrong, but I can't figure it out

Comment: I am not going to downvote you but it is clear you did not spend much time debugging.  It took me longer to copy your code to my development environment then it did finding and fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fila.SelectNodes still iterates through the entire document so you iterating through all 4 `td` nodes 3 times (once per `tr` node).  Try this code instead...

```
public static List<Parada> parsear(string html)
{
    int cual = 0;
    int _parada = 0;
    string _destino = "";
    List<Parada> lp = new List<Parada>();
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    foreach (HtmlNode tabla in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr//td"))
    {
        cual = 1 - cual;
        if (cual == 1)
        {
            _parada = Int32.Parse(tabla.InnerText);
        }
        else
        {
            _destino = tabla.InnerText;
            lp.Add(new Parada(_parada , _destino));
        }
    }

    return lp;
}
```

Comment: I get an error with `celda.InnerText`, I changed it to `tabla.InnerText`. When I have the header and one row seems to work fine. But with a header and 2 rows, now I get 3 rows instead of 6.

Comment: Now the logic works fine, I fixed the _else_ part... `_destino = tabla.InnerText`and `lp.Add(new Parada(_parada, _destino))` . Thanks and sorry, this is actually my first time with this library, and parsing xml altogether.